# How to add a PCM Device in /dev/snd

Tags: android, linux-device-driver, alsa, android-kernel, tinyalsa

Currently under /dev/snd/, I have the following devices

```
controlC0
pcmC0D0c
pcmC0D0p
timer
```

How do I add another device (i.e. pcmC0D1p)? The system is running Android, and it currently uses tiny ALSA for audio.

Comment: Write a sound driver for another device, and load it.

Comment: I suppose it reflects only actual hardware. If you have connected something else (new codec) you have to find / modify or write a new driver for it.

Answer (score 1):

Requirements for a new soundcard (not what asked, but maybe what was meant):

- Your new audio hardware is connected.
- The kernel is compiled with a driver for the new hardware.
- Your Android build's device-tree has configuration information, if the device uses an I2S, I2C, SPI or other low-level connection.

`pcmC0D1p` is another (p)layback device *on the same soundcard* `pcmC0` (card 0).

If the soundcard, kernel and device-tree all support it, it will appear.